# Grub menu appearing Black instead of purple Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

So I googled up a solution to a previously existing problem which required me to long press SHIFT button during start up. It turned the grub menu like this..
[Image of my Grub menu now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUpmf.jpg)

Before everything happened it used to look somewhat like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U94h1.jpg) 
 (Except that there was Windows 10 instead of Windows 7)

[This is how my Grub file looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gwHy.jpg)(Click)

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
>   .#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
>   .#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
>   GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
>   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
>   .#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
>   GRUB_TERMINAL=console
>   GRUB_GFXMODE=640X480
>   .#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
>   .#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
>   .#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

It gives an Error before boot saying **error: no video mode activated** [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbaNF.jpg)
Although It works Normally..It is Irritating .. How do i fix the Error and get the Purple Grub menu back? :/ Thanks in Advance :)

**Edit:**
Thanks to Pratap the both the problems are now solved.

> Hi, Regarding the Error i am working on it. Meanwhile can you add # before GRUB_TERMINAL=console and before GRUB_GFXMODE=640X480. After adding # symbols , save the file & close. open terminal and sudo update-grub once updated. close the terminal and reboot the system to see the change.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That Solved all the problems i had including The ERROR part... I think the error thing was also related to it :) Thanks again

Comment: Sure! (Would upvote if i could just dont have enough reputation sorry!)

Comment: @VrushankV I've upvoted on your behalf. Which I probably would have done anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `#` before `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` and before `GRUB_GFXMODE=640X480`.
After adding `#` symbols , save the file & close.

Open Terminal and run `sudo update-grub`.
Once updated, close the terminal and reboot the system to see the change.